# Wireless networks not working Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I don't have any menu about wireless in my network menu, only a grey option called "Ethernet Network (Intel Wireless 8260)". "Edit connections" also doesn't show wireless. In "Software and Updates", there is nothing related to wireless or broadcom in the additional drivers section. However, "sudo iwlist scan" does give the correct available wireless network connections, I just would like to see them in the network menu with some kind of "enable wifi" option.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.845559] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.845569] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.845576] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.867713] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.905820] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    3.908222] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.909701] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.912224] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.066647] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.072160] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.391612] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.392034] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.392795] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.529621] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.530538] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.531730] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
```

Comment: Are you able to create a wireless network under `Edit connections` using your router's SSID?

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: New output included.
I can add  a wifi network under `Edit connections`, but I prefer not to use this method for every wifi network I want to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself. After restarting, I could see all the available wifi networks. Maybe because it's a new laptop, it wasn't done updating or something. Also, I was on a different location where security issues might have prevented me from seeing the wifi.